# How do I stop my mac from running all these processes?

Tags: unix

My computer has around 400 processes, and I have no clue where they come from. It is taking up an immense amount of space and preventing me from running many programs. I've tried a lot to kill individual processes, but they seem to come back. I don't think it's a forkbomb. All I know is that it is not good. I uninstalled xcode, android studio, and docker. I have rebooted, logged in and out, etc.

[image: Here is an image of my terminal---couldn't copy and paste all the text.]
Any solutions?

Comment: Your browser is the heaviest process running. You might want to periodically quit and relaunch it.

Comment: Activity Monitor gives a clearer picture of what is happening including graphs of memory and CPU use.

Comment: Also, if you want a continuous overview, menu-bar accessories such as iStat Menus can show you info on processor, memory, disk, network, &c usage (in as much or little detail as you want).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These processes are part of macOS and required by the system, or applications you started yourself. If you look at the MEM and CPU columns you see that they neither need a lot of memory nor a lot of processing time.